# XSLT concat, trasnlate to uppercase

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to concat and trasnlate to upper-case in XSLT with the below coding:

```
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(E_Firstname, ',', E_Lastname, $uppercase)"/>
```

However, it just adds ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ to the field I am trying to transform into all caps.  Can you someone tell me what this syntax should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want:

```
translate(concat(E_Firstname, ',', E_Lastname), $lowercase, $uppercase)
```